# Emulator is not running after AOSP Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: emulation, android-source

After building successfully by `~$ make -j` , if I run  `~$emulator`  it shows below problem.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

> sh: 1: glxinfo: not found emulator: WARNING: system partition size
>   adjusted to match image file (1792 MB > 200 MB)
>
> emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file
>   (550 MB > 200 MB)
>
> sh: 1: glxinfo: not found emulator: WARNING: encryption is off X Error
>   of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()   Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  2   Serial number of failed request:  35   Current serial
>   number in output stream:  36 QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be
>   stopped from another thread